# How to measure the network traffic for my new UPD broadcast application

Tags: c#, networking, udp, broadcast

I am now upgrading a multi tier real time application. Now, we have 2 tier of application which is low level, and mid level.

There are more than 100 workstations for the low level application. This Low level application will sending all status of hardware (like alarm of low paper and error printer) to the mid level using a UDP. We need to specify the port and the IP address of Mid level at the low level application.

For Mid level application, we have around 20 workstations that receive all the alarm from the low level and display it in 2D graphical.

Now, we have a new requirement to add 1 more tier (high level), which is located at the Head quarters. This high level application will display all the alarm information from the low level application.

I am planning to use a broadcast features in UDP. It will easier for the installation team and development team to make it. But I am worried that, it will consume a lot of network bandwidth.

I don't have a lot of experience in networking. I don't know what is the measurement that should I use. What kind of input that I need to consider if I want to use a broadcast UDP. What is the best network infra should I use. What kind of test should I make. And even what kind of question should I ask for this.

Any of suggestion and comment are most welcome.

Answer (score 0):

you cloud use wireshark to see the traffic that is incoming and out going. You could measure that on one of the low level machines and the just simply multiply that value with amount of workstations. 
Or if have a switch that analysis the packages that it transmits you can see the Broadcast amount on the webinterface. 
But beware the broadcasts are only transmitted in the same network depending on the subneting. You may consider using a multicast domain instead of just broadcasting.